# RequestError while updating the index in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a record indexed in the elasticsearch with certain timestamp. I am trying to update the record using the following code (in python):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

es = Elasticsearch()
time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
msg = {'_id': 1, 'text': 'Hello World'}
es.index(index='idx', doc_type='dtype', id=msg['_id'], body=msg, timestamp=time, ttl='30d')
msg['text'] = 'New Message'
es.update(index='idx', doc_type='dtype', id=msg['_id'], body=msg, timestamp=time, ttl='30d')
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;]')
```

What could be the reason for the same?

Comment: Hey @mirchi, I hope my answer helped you. If that's the case, don't forget to accept if it :)

Comment: Thanks @heschoon. I am not sure how to accept the same.

Comment: to accept a question, you must click on the big green "V" under the upvote / downvote arrows on the left of the answer. It "closes" the question, marking the problem as solved.

Answer (score 14):

The message number 400 means that you have a "Bad request". The request body/URL is not what is expected.

In this case, it is due to the fact that you don't use a script or a doc in the body. Have a look at the [Update API documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) for more information.

The following code solves your problem:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

es = Elasticsearch()
time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
msg = {'_id': 1, 'text': 'Hello World'}
es.index(index='idx', doc_type='dtype', id=msg['_id'], body=msg, timestamp=time, ttl='30d')
msg2 = '''{"doc": {"text": "New Message"}}'''
es.update(index='idx', doc_type='dtype', id=msg['_id'], body=msg2, timestamp=time, ttl='30d')
```

By surrounding the information you want to change by a `doc` tag, you tell ElasticSearch that you want to replace the values with those of the partial document.